# Is there a way to give something more than 1 point for an outstanding answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, up-votes

I've read a few answers to questions recently that I have found to be above excellent and well into outstanding.  In these cases I would like some sort of ability to either give something beyond the 1 point upvote - even if it were some of my own reputation points.  Something like a reverse bouty where I can give a few of my own points directly to another user.

Is there any way to do this or is this a new feature request :)

Comment: Lance's answer covers your options.  Giving away some of your rep directly to an answerer has been discussed before and declined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do the following to reward the answerer:

1. Upvote the answer for 10 rep.
2. Accept the answer gives 15 rep.
3. You can set a bounty on the question, then (after some delay) reward
   it to that answer.

Note, that placing a bounty on the question will also draw more attention to it, thereby probably garnering even more votes for the good answers.

Comment: In addition, adding a bounty to the question will attract attention and get the question you like even more upvotes.

Comment: These questions are not my own, but belong to someone else.  I was looking to reward someone else's answer to someone else's question.

Comment: @Michael, You can set a bounty on someone else's question.

Comment: This may or may not belong in a separate question, but if I place a bounty on a question that I didn't ask, do I still have control over where the bounty goes?

Comment: @Jack, yes, if you award it manually.  The system will auto-reward it (on not reward it) if you don't.  Either way the bounty is spent.