# Can I give more than +1 on an answer to someone others question?

Tags: support, answers, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we have a small number of Supervotes per day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day)

While being similar to [Is there a way to give something more than 1 point for an outstanding answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106172/is-there-a-way-to-give-something-more-than-1-point-for-an-outstanding-answer), my question is about answers to a question from someone else.

I have e.g. been struggling with Spinners on Android. Someone else posted the question I was about to post and one of the answers solved my issue. As this really saved my time (and it was the best of all the dozens of suggestions), I'd like to give that answer more than just a +1.

As this is not my own question, I can neither accept it, nor offer a bounty.

Just asking the question again in the hope that that guy is again answering is definitively wrong (and I expect that the question will be closed being a dupe).

So what can I do here?

Comment: I'd also like to vote more than once in the coming government elections because I feel strongly for one of the parties. *Please*?

Comment: Share it with your friends and get them to upvote it too if they deem it worthy ;-)

Comment: @DanielBeck: Two of the upvotes on your comment are from me. No, really they are. Because I like it a whole lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can post a bounty on anyone's question. Just do that, you'll even get a badge (or two) for it.

The question just needs to be 48 hours old. Be patient if that's not the case.

For full details, visit: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: Interesting, did not know that. The usual waiting time still applies even if Q&A are already old?

Comment: The limitation is on the age of the question. If it's more than two days old, you can put a bounty on it. (The age of the answers, if any,  doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 4):

You can offer bounties on others' questions, after some time, even if they already have an accepted answer.

So you could offer a bounty, add to the note that the bounty will go to one specific user, and then award it to them as soon as possible.